# Better way to upload files along with field data

Tags: reactjs, express, formik, formik-material-ui

I am currently working on a application with React as frontend and Nodejs as backend.

I am using multer and minIO to store the files.

Currently:
I have a form where the user fills up some data and also has the option to upload files such as PDF/JPEG etc (multiple input fields for file).

I am using forkmik along with material UI for validation and styling.

So when a user fills up the form (data is a json object), if there is any file upload done it does a POST request to "/upload" uploads the file to the storage engine and then returns a path of where the file is stored.

Then I send one more POST request to "/" to save the user info along with the path that it returned earlier onto MongoDB.

I trying to make it as a single post request to "/" but cannot do so, this is what I have tried,

is to send the user info with content-type "multipart/form-data" along with the files, I am only able to get the "req.files" array properly while the "req.body" of the user information is shown as "[Object: null prototype] { 'values.general_information.first_name': 'Amy',
'values.general_information.last_name': 'John' }" and so on.

I am trying to receive it in a proper json format but cannot do so.

Answer (score 0):

Since the data I was receiving was [Object: null prototype], in the body converted to string using JSON.stringify() and on the backend parsed the incoming data using JSON.parse(), without using react FormData and was able to make it into a single POST request using multipart/form-data as I was uploading files as well.